# Получить разрешение на отправку сообщений ботом от имени сообщества ВК

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу Бота для ВК Сообщества на Python.

У меня есть файлы пользователей, в которых хранится их информация для Бота.

Мне нужно, чтобы этим пользователям отправлялась рассылка в 00:00.

Я получил имена их файлов, получил таким образом их `id`, занёс в список, но ВК пишет, что:

`Нельзя отправить сообщение без права/разрешения`

Можете помочь?

UPD:

Прочитав документацию, я использовал метод: `showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox` для получения разрешения, но после указания `group_id` в методе, мне выдало:

`int object has no attribute 'copy'`

```py
                            group_id = 1234567890

                            #Код

                            if msg_lower == 'вкл рассылку' or msg_lower == 'включить рассылку' or msg_lower ==  'рассылка вкл' or msg_lower == 'вкл рассылка':
                                answered = True

                                way = 'Data/Users/'+str(id)+'.dat'

                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                if newsletter_summerDay == 'Включена':
                                    sender(id, 'Рассылка и так включена!', '')
                                if newsletter_summerDay == 'Выключена':
                                    sender(id, 'Для включения рассылки нажмите "OK" в появившемся окне', '')
                                    vk_session.method("showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox", group_id)

                                    if event.onAllowMessagesFromCommunityCancel:
                                        time.sleep(0.5)
                                        sender(id, 'Вы отменили включение рассылки', '')
                                    elif event.onAllowMessagesFromCommunity:
                                        time.sleep(0.5)
                                        sender(id, 'Включаю рассылку...', '')
                                        path = pathlib.Path(way); path.write_text(path.read_text().replace('Рассылка (Какой день лета): Выключена', 'Рассылка (Какой день лета): Включена'))
                                        time.sleep(0.5)
                                        sender(id, 'Рассылка включена!', '')
```

Сообщение `Для включения рассылки нажмите "OK" в появившемся окне` отправляется, но после вк метода ничего не работает.

Comment: После разрешения генерируется `событие onAllowMessagesFromCommunity`. попробуйте отловить событие и посмотреть что в нём.

Comment: Да, но оно не может сгенерироваться из-за ошибки.
Добавил больше кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Чтобы Вы могли отправлять пользователю сообщения от имени сообщества, пользователь должен разрешить их получение**.

Если пользователь написал сообщение сообществу первым, это приравнивается к согласию на получение ответных сообщений (без ограничений по времени, если пользователь не запретил сообщения вручную).

Чтобы запросить у пользователя разрешение на отправку сообщений, используйте:

- Метод [showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox](https://vk.com/dev/clientapi?f=15.%20showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox) Client API в приложениях сообществ;
- Метод [messages.allowMessagesFromGroup](https://vk.com/dev/messages.allowMessagesFromGroup) в Standalone-приложениях;
- Виджет «[Разрешить писать сообществу](https://vk.com/dev/AllowMessagesFromCommunity)» на внешнем сайте.

В [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) и [Bots Longpoll API](https://vk.com/dev/bots_longpoll) события **message_allow** и **message_deny** помогут отслеживать факт разрешения и запрета сообщений от сообщества.

**Обратите внимание**, получить список всех пользователей, разрешивших сообщения сообществу, через API нельзя, необходимо хранить и синхронизировать этот список на своей стороне.

[Источник](https://vk.com/dev/bizmessages_doc?f=2.%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Komedik, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Да, конечно.
Только, мне написали:
int has not attribute 'copy' после указания group_id
Что это значит?

Comment: обновите свой вопрос и укажите код и ошибку, без контекста трудно сказать, а вообще "не все объекты имеют метод `copy`, как `dict`"

Comment: Сейчас создам новый вопрос и скину Вам ссылку

Comment: достаточно обновить текущий вопрос с помощью кнопки Править

Comment: Хорошо. Сейчас напишу

Comment: приведите больше кода и в виде текста